# How to show total rows one time in PostgreSQL select results?

Tags: postgresql

```
select  (select count(*) from sync.request) as total,
        retry_count,
        count(retry_count)
from sync.request
GROUP BY retry_count
```

This returns for example:

```
299 0   246
299 1   20
299 3   14
299 2   19
```

The 299 is correct but it's in every row. Is there a way to have the results as follows:

```
299
0 246
1 20
3 14
2 19
```

I'm trying to get a quick total to show by itself with the rest of the results.

Comment: Use two separate queries. Your desired result isn't even tabular.

Comment: At best, use a `UNION ALL (SELECT null AS request, count(*) AS total FROM sync.request)`